# concat two video using ffmpeg working on local but not working on server why?

Tags: laravel, video, ffmpeg, server, concatenation

Here the code is for `concat` two video and adding watermark to that video but this code working perfectly in local but not in server.

**The code is as follows:**

```
$videoFileName = rand('111111', '999999').'_'.time().'.'.$request->file('video1')->getClientOriginalExtension();

$intermediateVideo1 = rand('1111111', '9999999').'_'.time().'.ts';
$intermediateVideo2 = rand('1111111', '9999999').'_'.time().'.ts';
$concatVideoFileName = rand('111111', '999999').'_'.time().'.'.$request->file('video1')->getClientOriginalExtension();

exec('ffmpeg -i '.$request->file('video1').' -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts '.$intermediateVideo1);
exec('ffmpeg -i '.$request->file('video2').' -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts '.$intermediateVideo2);
exec('ffmpeg -i "concat:'.$intermediateVideo1.'|'.$intermediateVideo2.'" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc '.public_path('uploads/videos/'.$concatVideoFileName));

exec('ffmpeg -i '.public_path('uploads/videos/'.$concatVideoFileName).' -i '.storage_path("assets/image/watermark.png").' -filter_complex "overlay" '.public_path('uploads/videos/'.$videoFileName));

File::delete($intermediateVideo1);
File::delete($intermediateVideo2);
File::delete(public_path('uploads/videos/'.$concatVideoFileName));
```

Comment: When you say its not working; what kind of not working ? Have you error logs ? Nothing ? Wrong result ? ... ?

Comment: Shows you some error ? Maybe you have not added the `use File;` to the top of the file.

Comment: not displayed any error.

Comment: @michal i added use File; problem is not in deleting file but in concatnation file not save in videos folder.

Comment: Can you run the commands directly via ssh to see what it outputs? Sounds like it may be a permission issue preventing you from moving the file to your uploads/videos/ folder.

Comment: And you sure the server has ffmpeg installed?

Comment: is there any solution? because i have same problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54568741/how-to-fix-ffmpeg-command-cannot-work-when-multiple-mp3-file-to-process-into-on