# ffmpeg concat two video and add watermark after concating video give me blank mp4 file on server but in local working perfectly why?

Tags: php, laravel, ffmpeg

i have two video i want to concat them and then add watermark to them but after command run give me blank mp4 file on server but in local working perfectly and on server two video concat perfectly but after that code is not running.

My code is as follows.

```
$videoFileName = rand('111111', '999999').'_'.time().'.'.$request->file('video1')->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $intermediateVideo1 = rand('1111111', '9999999').'_'.time().'.ts';
    $intermediateVideo2 = rand('1111111', '9999999').'_'.time().'.ts';
    $concatVideoFileName = rand('111111', '999999').'_'.time().'.'.$request->file('video1')->getClientOriginalExtension();

    exec('ffmpeg -i '.$request->file('video1').' -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts '.$intermediateVideo1);
    exec('ffmpeg -i '.$request->file('video2').' -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts '.$intermediateVideo2);
    exec('ffmpeg -i "concat:'.$intermediateVideo1.'|'.$intermediateVideo2.'" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc '.public_path('uploads/videos/'.$concatVideoFileName));

    exec('ffmpeg -i '.public_path('uploads/videos/'.$concatVideoFileName).' -i '.storage_path("assets/image/watermark.png").' -filter_complex "overlay" '.public_path('uploads/videos/'.$videoFileName));


    File::delete($intermediateVideo1);
    File::delete($intermediateVideo2);
    File::delete('uploads/videos/'.$concatVideoFileName);

    return response()->download(public_path('uploads/videos/'.$videoFileName));
```

**output of intermediate video1:**

> ffmpeg version 2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the
>   FFmpeg developers   built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu
>   5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609   configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv   libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100   libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100   libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101   libavdevice    56.  4.100 /
>   56.  4.100   libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101   libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0   libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101   libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101   libpostproc    53.  3.100 /
>   53.  3.100 Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'storage/assets/video/vcs-ads.mp4':   Metadata:
>       major_brand     : mp42
>       minor_version   : 0
>       compatible_brands: mp42mp41isomavc1
>       creation_time   : 2018-01-29 00:23:59   Duration: 00:00:13.76, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 460 kb/s
>       Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m), 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 327 kb/s, 29.97
>   fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
>       Metadata:
>         creation_time   : 2018-01-29 00:23:59
>         handler_name    : L-SMASH Video Handler
>         encoder         : AVC Coding
>       Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
>       Metadata:
>         creation_time   : 2018-01-29 00:23:59
>         handler_name    : L-SMASH Audio Handler Output #0, mpegts, to '1234567_12324.ts':   Metadata:
>       major_brand     : mp42
>       minor_version   : 0
>       compatible_brands: mp42mp41isomavc1
>       encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
>       Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 327 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr,
>   90k tbn, 30k tbc (default)
>       Metadata:
>         creation_time   : 2018-01-29 00:23:59
>         handler_name    : L-SMASH Video Handler
>         encoder         : AVC Coding
>       Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, 128 kb/s (default)
>       Metadata:
>         creation_time   : 2018-01-29 00:23:59
>         handler_name    : L-SMASH Audio Handler Stream mapping:   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)   Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy) Press [q] to stop, [?] for help frame=  412 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=     898kB
>   time=00:00:13.76 bitrate= 534.5kbits/s     video:550kB audio:215kB
>   subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead:
>   17.329643%

Comment: Has the video at `$concatVideoFileName` been successful? Are the versions of ffmpeg on local and server the same?

Comment: yes video at $concatVideoFileName has been successful but version of ffmpeg on local and server are not same

Comment: Successful as in you have downloaded it and checked that it is not blank

Comment: yes concatnated video is not blank and also downloaded.

Comment: Show complete log/console output of `ffmpeg -i video1 -i video2`

Comment: Also, please avoid asking [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48885890/concat-two-video-using-ffmpeg-working-on-local-but-not-working-on-server-why) more than once.

Comment: Hello @LordNeckbeard output of video1 and video2 is $intemediateVideo1 and 2 that is in .ts format and it is working

Comment: @LordNeckbeard i just updated my question.

Comment: @JinalSomaiya This is helpful but only half of the requested information. I also need to see the details of `ffmpeg -i $intemediateVideo2`. Marking as code instead of quote will make it easier to read.